# Select Update statement in oracle range selection

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-update, date-range

I am trying to select all data from oracle table where emp_id = emp_id_in and date range between example -- 9/3/2011 and 9/6/2011

and once it's selected I want to update one of the field for all of the selected data. How can I do this in oracle? What type of select and update statment do I need to do this? Any example would be really helpful.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need a select and an update. You can do it with UPDATE alone.

Try this:

```
UPDATE someTable
   SET yourField = <SOME-VALUE>
 WHERE emp_id = emp_id_in
   AND some_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('9/3/2011', 'MM/DD/RRRR') AND TO_DATE('9/6/2011', 'MM/DD/RRRR')
```